# Wso2am custom sequence - how to get scimid from jwt

Tags: wso2

```
<property name="authheader" expression="get-property('transport','X-JWT-Assertion')"></property>
```

I am not getting value from `authheader`, added this code in wso2 sequence in flow to get `scim` id at the end service.

Comment: How are you trying to access the value ?

Comment: @mrid using this below blog code https://lahiruwrites.blogspot.in/2016/06/access-jwt-token-in-mediator-extension.html?view=flipcard

Comment: Minimal markup improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have enabled JWT token generation in your deployment as given in [1].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT

Comment: okay. Do you see the "Enduser" property value logged in the server log?

Comment: it is coming in log but when i use in the to get from header it is coming as null ...

Comment: String scimId = rctx.request().getHeader("Enduser")); scimId is null

Comment: thanks it is working now , added this below code to set it to header   <property expression="get-property('enduser')" name="scimId" scope="transport" >